Need help migrating CentOS to Ubuntu
I'm having troubles migrating a CentOS 7 to an ubuntu server, currently we have migrated to Rocky Linux, but we would like to migrate to an ubuntu server because of the updates. The server is using Suricata, Zerotier agent and DWagent services, and we would like to transfer them and all the system configuration to the Ubuntu server, we don't need the exact configuration but an approximation.
We have been looking for documentation, but it is non-existent and we are genuinely lost, we tried to transfer the /usr/share/dwagent directory from CentOS to Ubuntu server, but obviously it isn't working.
The second option we have is installing ubuntu in another partition on the CentOS server, but because we want to do it remotely we can't afford to lose contact with the server and we are not seeing any possible option to do it without losing it.
Looking for documentation (non-existent) and asked ubuntu for support. Transferring service files to the new server (not working, failed to start) Partial migration to rocky Linux (working but we prefer ubuntu) Installing ubuntu in the CentOS machine (in progress).

Welcome to AskUbuntu. This site works best if you ask a single, specific, clear, answerable question. "We want help adding these three services" is not single or clear (what's the problem?), and therefore may be unlikely to attract useful answers. If you are having trouble adding dwagent, then ask a question about the specific problem you are encountering.

There is documentation here:
https://ubuntu.com/engage/migrating-from-rhel-centos-to-ubuntu-public-cloud
This should cover the basics. There are so many factors at play here that a 1:1 migration will probably not be possible.
I would strongly suggest installing Ubuntu Server on a new machine (or VM/Cloud/whatever), so that you always have your existing CentOS installation running alongside, until everything is migrated and working correctly.

Yeah, We saw that document a while ago, but unfortunately, it doesn't help much. We know a 1:1 migration is impossible, but we at least need to make the three services work on Ubuntu with the same configuration. Unfortunately, we haven't been able to do it yet. As I mentioned in the previous post, we need Suricata, DWagent, and Zerotier to work with the same config files. Even when transferring them, all services end up failing to start. I would appreciate some help, at least with these specific services.

I'm not familiar with those services - but I would assume this requires to go through the configuration documentation to set each of them up correctly on Ubuntu.

Suricata Version: 1:6.0.4-3 is available from the standard Ubuntu repos.  The others aren't.
